# How to convert a JAVAScript object into a Map<String,String> in JAVA?

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, parsing

I'm new here and New to the concept of JAVA and JavaScript.
I have a requirement for my current assignment for which I need to convert a JavaScript Object into a JAVA Map (or any other relevant DATASTRUCTURE) without using(or creating) a new POJO.

Below is how my object looks like:

```
var objectJavaScript = {
        key1: "value1",
        key2: "value2",
        key3: "value3"
};
```

I have declared an Array and have pushed many of these objects into that array.

Now I am sending this array into my ServiceClass in JAVA. Here I need these objects back so that I can use their Value.

NOTE: The number of these Objects in the Array is never fixed and can change on each call.

Comment: Youll convert it into a JSON string in javascript ( JSON.stringify(yourarray) ). Then take a Java Parser and parse it

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jArray;
String s = jArray.toString()
```

Pass your string s to back-end,
convert string s back to `JSONArray`, as

```
JSONArray newJArray = new JSONArray(s);
```

Loop over the `JSONArray`,get every `JSONObject`
and get your `key` and `value` from `JSONObject`, put into `Map`

Comment: Didn't work.
@praveen    do u mean to code this{
JSONArray jArray;
String s = jArray.toString()
}
in JavaScript??

Comment: var j={"name":"binchen"};
JSON.stringify(j);

try this out with  JSON.stringify
@akashrsingh